# flutter : how RadioListTile Button will be in center?

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, flutter-animation

This is my code I want to center my radioListTile Button.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import '../Utils/GlobalColor/global_color.dart';
import '../Utils/GlobalTextStyles/global_text_styles.dart';
import '../Utils/GlobalWidgetPages/app_bar_center_text.dart';

class SavedAddressesPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const SavedAddressesPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<SavedAddressesPage> createState() => _SavedAddressesPageState();
}

class _SavedAddressesPageState extends State<SavedAddressesPage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: MyColor.bgLightColor,
      appBar: AppBarWithCenterText(
        text: "Saved Addresses",
        onPressed: () {
          Navigator.pop(context);
        },
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: RadioListTile(
          dense: true,
          contentPadding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 13, right: 13, top: 0, bottom: 16),
          title: Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 13, right: 13, top: 16, bottom: 16),
            height: 100,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
              border: Border.all(color: MyColor.greyColor),
            ),
            child: Column(
              children: [
                Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                  children: [
                    Row(
                      children: [
                        Image.asset(
                          "assets/outline_location_pin.png",
                          height: 18,
                          width: 17,
                          color: MyColor.blueColor,
                        ),
                        SizedBox(
                          width: 4,
                        ),
                        Text(
                          'Office',
                          style: textStyleWith14500(MyColor.blackColor),
                          maxLines: 1,
                          overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                    Row(
                      children: [
                        InkWell(onTap: (){
                          print("edit");
                        },
                          child: Container(
                              height: 18,
                              width: 18,
                              child: Icon(
                                Icons.edit,
                                size: 16,
                                color: MyColor.blueColor,
                              )),
                        ),
                        SizedBox(
                          width: 14,
                        ),
                        InkWell(onTap: (){
                          print("delete_outline");
                        },
                          child:
                        Container(
                            height: 18,
                            width: 18,
                            child: Icon(
                              Icons.delete_outline,
                              size: 16,
                              color: MyColor.primaryRedColor,
                            )),)
                      ],
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 9,
                ),
                Text(
                  "D-787 High Tower Appt., Flat No. 202, In White House Lane, Street View, USA.",
                  style: textStyleWith12400(MyColor.darkGreyColor),
                  maxLines: 2,
                  overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          value: "male",
          groupValue: 0,
          onChanged: (value) {
            setState(() {
              print(value.toString());
            });
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

This is my UI

[image]

But In Actuall I want like this

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This would work, but using RadioListTile wouldn't make much sense in this case. The radio can be added to the leader using the regular ListTile.

```dart
child: RadioListTile(
  controlAffinity: ListTileControlAffinity.trailing,
  secondary: Column(
    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
    children: [
      Radio(value: 1, groupValue: 0, onChanged: (value) {}),
    ],
  ),
  // ...
),
```

```dart
child: ListTile(
  leading: Column(
    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
    children: [
      Radio(value: 1, groupValue: 0, onChanged: (value) {}),
    ],
  ),
  // ...
),
```

Comment: no Its not working

Comment: I tried in your code and it worked. This would work, but using RadioListTile wouldn't make much sense in this case. The radio can be added to the leader using the regular ListTile.

Comment: can you send full code which is worked

Comment: You are right it doesn't work. I observed that since the ListTile is long on the horizontal screen, it is perfectly centered. But when you try it on the vertical screen, it is not centered because it shrinks.

Comment: It needs to be custom made

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap RadioListTile under container widget and make align center like below code example :

```
Container(
    alignment: Alignment.center, // Align the RadioListTile button to center
    child: RadioListTile(
      dense: true,
      contentPadding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 13, right: 13, top: 0, bottom: 16),
      title: Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 13, right: 13, top: 16, bottom: 16),
        height: 100,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
          border: Border.all(color: MyColor.greyColor),
        ),
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
              children: [
                Row(
                  children: [
                    Image.asset(
                      "assets/outline_location_pin.png",
                      height: 18,
                      width: 17,
                      color: MyColor.blueColor,
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      width: 4,
                    ),
                    Text(
                      'Office',
                      style: textStyleWith14500(MyColor.blackColor),
                      maxLines: 1,
                      overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
                Row(
                  children: [
                    InkWell(onTap: (){
                      print("edit");
                    },
                      child: Container(
                          height: 18,
                          width: 18,
                          child: Icon(
                            Icons.edit,
                            size: 16,
                            color: MyColor.blueColor,
                          )),
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      width: 14,
                    ),
                    InkWell(onTap: (){
                      print("delete_outline");
                    },
                      child:
                    Container(
                        height: 18,
                        width: 18,
                        child: Icon(
                          Icons.delete_outline,
                          size: 16,
                          color: MyColor.primaryRedColor,
                        )),)
                  ],
                ),
              ],
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: 9,
            ),
            Text(
              "D-787 High Tower Appt., Flat No. 202, In White House Lane, Street View, USA.",
              style: textStyleWith12400(MyColor.darkGreyColor),
              maxLines: 2,
              overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      value: "male",
      groupValue: 0,
      onChanged: (value) {
        setState(() {
          print(value.toString());
        });
      },
    ),
  ),
```